# Concatenating hierarchical file paths in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SQL Schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE Folders(
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     path TEXT NOT NULL, 
     level INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
     parentId INTEGER)
```

an item with parentId != NULL is a root item and has the full path in "path". Subfolders are only saved by their name and a level that describes how far below the root folder they are. I now want to build the full paths for all items from this data.

CTE is not available in SQLite so I created this query to fetch the full paths of items:

```
select f.id, ifnull(group_concat(p.path, '\')||'\', '')||f.path as path
  from folders f 
  left outer join (select * from folders order by parentId, level) p on (p.parentId=f.parentId or p.id=f.parentId) and p.level < f.level
  group by f.id
```

However this seems to be highly inefficient when I look at the execution plan with "explain". I created an index on parentId, path and level but this does not seem to improve much.

I tried to check http://www.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/ but it has a redirect problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that if the number of levels between root and children is variable. What you did is incorrect and at best you could join a root with direct children.

There are different solutions to code hierarchical data into tables and avoid the need for recursive queries. E.g., see https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-9902.

Since one of the solutions is to have materialised paths, you should realise that in fact what you need is to have the full path in every record, which gives you the data you need with a simple query.

Comment: yes you are right, that's an edge case I did not see. Saving the full path it is then. Still keeping the parentId though.